# PHPUnit API Testing returns unauthenticated in some post requests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to test my Laravel API, but in some cases where I submit a post request I receive a 401 error with the message "Unauthenticated". All the GET requests that are protected are properly accessible and certain POST requests like submitting a status are also doing fine. Why do I get the 401 error in some cases, but not in others?

Here are the files 
**API Routes**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
    Route::get('logout', [MantelAuthController::class, 'logout']);
    
    Route::post('status', [MantelController::class, 'status']);
    Route::post('deleteAccount', [MantelController::class, 'deleteAccount']);
});
```

**Logout test**

```php
public function test_logoutAPI()
    {
        $testEmail = getenv('TEST_EMAIL_API');
        $testPassword = getenv('TEST_PASSWORD_API');

        $response = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'email' => $testEmail,
            'password' => $testPassword
        ]);

        $auth =  $response->assertStatus(201)->decodeResponseJson()['token'];
        
        $response = $this->get('/api/logout', 
        [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$auth
        ]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

**Send status test**

```php
public function test_post_status()
    {
        $testEmail = getenv('TEST_EMAIL_API2');
        $testPassword = getenv('TEST_PASSWORD_API');

        // log in
        $response = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'email' => $testEmail,
            'password' => $testPassword
        ]);
        $auth = $response->assertStatus(201)->decodeResponseJson()['token'];

        // get correct datetime
        $response = $this->get('/api/getData', 
        [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$auth
        ]);
        $date= $response->assertStatus(200)->decodeResponseJson()['date'];
        
        // submit post request
        $response = $this->post('/api/status', 
        [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$auth,
            'status' => "secure",
            'date' => $date
        ]);
        $response->assertCreated();
    }
```

**Delete Account test**

```php
public function test_delete_account()
    {
        $DeletedEmail = "temporary@gmail.com";
        $DeletedPassword = "temporary";

        $response = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'email' => $DeletedEmail,
            'password' => $DeletedPassword
        ]);
        $auth = $response->assertStatus(201)->decodeResponseJson()['token'];
        
        $response = $this->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
        ->post('/api/deleteAccount', [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$auth,
            'password' => $DeletedPassword
        ]);
        $response->assertSuccessful();
    }
```

Comment: First of all, do not use `getenv`, if Laravel changes what it is using for that, `getenv` will start failing... you have to use `env` or `config`... Also, NEVER call more than 1 endpoint in your tests... you have to setup everything that you will expect to have in that moment... because if one of those previous API fails and creates or returns something wrong, you are done for that test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your issue is you are mixing your header data and post data. You should try using `withHeaders`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#customizing-request-headers

```
$response = $this->withHeaders([
            'X-Header' => 'Value',
        ])->post('/user', ['name' => 'Sally']);
```

You also don't have to actually login via your API route request for every test as this is pretty inefficient. You should have a test for your login API route, but you should be accessing the user model and using `actingAs` to set the authentication for your other requests.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#sessions-and-authentication

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
             ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
             ->visit('/')
             ->see('Hello, '.$user->name);
    }
}
```